# Reload uiview in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am parsing xml and get data and show this data on view, now i have to add reload button, which reload my view and call again xml parsing function, now problem is that how can i remove all contents on view and again show???

Comment: please be more specific. What you have on your view please post a screenshot.

Comment: My grab is not properly working. I've 3 lables one image view and one button on scroll view, i am doing all programmatic except one background image on nib?

Comment: i already tried removefromsuperview

Comment: [Self.view removefromsuperview]

From where you are.Give me your skype.I will tell you in detail

Comment: Yar buri bat hai kisi ko apna skypeid nahi deitay.Ab maff kar raha hn ainda na hoaasay  lolz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading and parsing the new data, call [setNeedsDisplay:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Implement drawRect: in the view such that it reflects the new data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mutables array for storing you xml data just remove all objects from array. Set nil to your labels's text and whatever you have on your view reload/download xml again and display on view.

Comment: Yar buri bat hai kisi ko apna skypeid nahi deitay.Ab maff kar raha hn ainda na hoaasay lolz... –